# Defining a variable after calling it?

Tags: python, variables, object

I've run into a problem in terms of assigning objects. I want to be able to assign the object via  a function, but because the variable `name` is not defined until during the function, when I first call the function (with name = john) it says:
    `NameError: name 'john' is not defined`.

I'm using this script to assist me while I run a game session, and I want to be able to create new NPC's at will, but is there anyway to do that without first using:
`>>> blahblah = Character()` 
in a python prompt?

Sorry for the block of code and I'm sorry if there is a simple solution.

```
import random
import math

combat_participants = []
npc_list = []

class Character():
    """Basic class for character statistics
    """
    def get_stats(self):
        """Refreshes the stats after new assignment
        """
        self.hp = self.st
        self.will = self.iq
        self.per = self.iq
        self.fp = self.ht
        self.bspeed = (self.ht + self.dx) / 4
        self.dodge = math.floor(self.bspeed + 3)
        self.bmove = math.floor(self.bspeed)
        self.blift = round(self.st*self.st/5)
    def get_status(self):
        """Checks the status of the character
        """
        if self.hp < -self.hp:
                self.status = 'Dead'
        elif self.hp < 0:
                self.status = 'Unconscious'
        else:
                self.status = 'Alive'
    #Primary Attributes
    st = 10
    dx = 10
    iq = 10
    ht = 10
    #Secondary Attributes
    hp = st
    will = iq
    per = iq
    fp = ht
    bspeed = (ht + dx) / 4
    dodge = math.floor(bspeed + 3)
    bmove = math.floor(bspeed)
    blift = round(st*st/5)
    #Other
    status = 'Alive'
    weapon = 'None'
    shield = 'None'
    char_name = ''

def create_npc(name, str_name, level, combat):
    """
    /long and irrelevant/
    """
    name = Character()
    name.char_name = str_name

    #Randomly assigning attributes
    prim_attr_list = [name.st, name.dx, name.iq, name.ht]
    for attr in prim_attr_list:
        attr = random.randint(7+level,9+level)
    name.get_stats(name)

    #Randomly assigns a weapon
    temp_weapon_list = []
    for weapon in weapon_list:
        if weapon.st <= name.st:
    temp_weapon_list += weapon
    name.weapon = temp_weapon_list[random.randint(0,len(temp_weapon_list)-1)]).wep_name

    #Adds them to the npc list
    global npc_list
    npc_list += [name]

    #Adds them to combat list if they are in combat
    global combat_participants
    if combat:
        combat_participants += [name]
```

EDIT:EDIT:After calling the function with create_npc('john', 'John Smithson II', 2, True)

Once I have assigned the Class obect as `'john'` rather than `john`, I don't know how to access it. For instance: `>>> john.char_name` will give me this error `NameError: name 'john' is not defined`, and `>>> 'john'.char_name` gives me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'char_name'`

Comment: Is it `john` or `"john"`?

Comment: And then what is `john`?

Comment: john is what I used for the argument `name`

Comment: As Medhat Gayed mentioned, it's not necessary to pass `name` as argument, but can you post the code where you *call the function*?

Comment: an example would be just this:
`create_npc('john', 'john smithson II', 2, True)`

Comment: That example won't throw the exception. You will get that error if you try to use a variable (in your case `john`) without initializing it before. Please, note that `john` is different than `"john"`, the last one is a string.

Comment: Ok, My question is now answered, thanks.

Comment: If you know something is "long and irrelevant", please kindly remove it from your post so we don't have to think about it. =/

Comment: I did remove it? It was the entire docstring

Comment: To access your characters later you have to loop through your npc_list e.g for x in npc_list and access your character name like x.char_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is add an `__init__()` method to your `Character` class. The following is a simplified `Character` class:

```
class Weapon:

    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.level = 1

    def upgrade(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.damage += 10

class Character:

    def __init__(self, name, level, weapon):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.weapon = weapon

        self.max_hp = self.get_max_hp()
        self.hp = max_hp

    def get_max_hp(self):
        return 100 + self.level*10

    def get_status(self):
        if self.hp <= 0:
            return 'Dead'
        elif self.hp < self.max_hp:
            return 'Unhealthy'
        else:
            return 'Healthy'

    def level_up(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.max_hp = self.get_max_hp()
        self.weapon.upgrade()

    def attack(self, npc):
        npc.hp -= self.weapon.damage

>>> sword = Weapon('sword', 15)
>>> spear = Weapon('spear', 20)
>>> npc1 = Character('john', 5, sword)
>>> npc2 = Character('james', 1, spear)
>>> npc1.name
'john'
>>> npc1.level
5
>>> npc1.max_hp
150
>>> npc1.weapon.name
'sword'
>>> npc1.weapon.damage
15
>>> npc1.weapon.upgrade()
>>> npc1.weapon.damage
25
>>> npc1.hp
150
>>> npc1.get_status()
'Healthy'
>>> npc2.attack(npc1)
>>> npc1.hp
130
>>> npc1.get_status()
'Unhealthy'
>>> for i in range(10):
        npc2.attack(npc1)
>>> npc1.hp
-70
>>> npc1.get_status()
'Dead'
>>> npc1.level_up()
>>> npc1.level
6
>>> npc1.weapon.damage
35
>>> npc1.max_hp
160
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense to me now

Comment: @KieranM I have added a weapon class and some more usage of the character class. Hopefully you should be able to figure out how to expand and adapt this for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass name to the function, remove that param from the function definition and your code should work fine.

Comment: Do I use str_name instead of name in this case:
`name = Character()`

Comment: You remove the name param from your create_npc function then just call it like *create_npc('john smithson II', 2, True)*